# How to scrape a website which changes its element on scroll?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web, web-scraping

[This](https://www.lkqonline.com/2020-Acura-Ilx-Engine-Assembly) is one of the links that I am trying to get data out of. This site changes its product element after scroll has reached to its 8th element.
its like there are more than 200 products given after a search query but the page source only shows 8 and when u scroll through the page then those 8 changes to next 8 products. As a result I am only able to get 8 product elements even after scrolling to end or rendering the page. Anyone knows how it would be possible to get all the products ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using infinite page scroll and printing the values we can achieve this. Requesting would be even better but was not allowed or not wanted.

```
driver.get('https://www.lkqonline.com/2020-Acura-Ilx-Engine-Assembly')
scroll_pause_time = 1 
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 1

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    elems=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.full-side')
    for elem in elems:
        print(elem.text)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break
```

Outputs

```
2020 Acura Ilx Used Engine Assembly - ~236203268
(2.4L, VIN 2, 6th digit)
Mileage: 33k
Location: SUMNER, WA
Source: 2016 Acura Ilx
Price: $1,592.00
2020 Acura Ilx Used Engine Assembly - ~261985457
(2.4L, VIN 2, 6th digit)
Mileage: 106k
Location: RANCHO CORDOVA, CA
Source: 2016 Acura Ilx
Price: $1,366.00
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The page display only a small amount of the products as it seems.

You can look at the requests that are made when you scroll down.

For example:

This is the first request that occurs when you load the page for the first time, notice the query param `skip=0`

```
https://www.lkqonline.com/api/catalog/0/product?catalogId=0&year=2020&make=ACURA&model=ILX&category=Engine%20Compartment%7CEngine%20Assembly&sort=closestFirst&skip=0&take=12&latitude=32.81556&longitude=34.98917
```

and the next request, after scrolling a bit is

```
https://www.lkqonline.com/api/catalog/0/product?catalogId=0&year=2020&make=ACURA&model=ILX&category=Engine%20Compartment%7CEngine%20Assembly&sort=closestFirst&skip=12&take=12&latitude=32.81556&longitude=34.98917
```

As you see, the only difference is that `skip` param, which now equals 12.

So to get all the products it seems you will have to make these requests , and increment that `skip` param by 12 until you reach the end.

Comment: I am not able to send direct get requests like that

Comment: why not? if you are scraping the website you are already making a request to that domain anyways.
So instead of requesting the whole page and then scraping, just request the specific urls for the product and avoid scraping at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get selenium to do the 'scrolling down' for you. This is the code. `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` As you scroll down, the html structure changes.

Now the question is when should the scrolling stop? For your website, it's a finite height (that means you can hit to the bottom of the page). So you probably have to write a small while loop to keep scrolling down until it hits to the bottom.